# What are the equivalent IPV6 versions of IPV4 special-use adresses?

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4, private-network

I'm trying to make a private network with 5 computers bellow an external [ADSL router](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSL_modem) with [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), but internally I want to use [IPV6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipv6). To do this I need to use private special-use IPV6 addresses, such as the well-known 192.168.x.x or 10.0.0.x [IPV4 address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipv4) blocks.

Does someone know what are the private IPV6 addresses for this specific use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia has an [article on non-routing IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), which includes IPv6:

The IPv6 addressing architecture [(RFC 4291)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291) sets aside the block `fe80::/10` for IP address autoconfiguration. All interfaces automatically get an address in this block; however, they are explicitly forbidden to be forwarded by routers.

If a locally routable address is needed, [unique local addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address) in `fc00::/7` can be used for a private network.

Finally, many LANs simply use a globally-routable prefix, since the large address space removes the need for a NAT in most of the cases.

Comment: That globally routed prefix should be provided by an internet provider though. Don't just pick a random one. If you want that, use ULA (unique local addresses). Also see http://www.sixxs.net/tools/grh/ula/

Comment: The authoritative reference for unique local IPv6 unicast addresses is [RFC 4193](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4193). Note that site-local addresses are no longer treated specially since [RFC 4291 section 2.5.7](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.7) and you should be using RFC 4193 addresses instead.